# Operation on new data.table affects old data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble with the data.table package in R (v1.9.6). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

I create a data.table and then assign this to a new variable. So now I have two data.tables. I then perform an operation on the second data.table. However this operation is also performed on the original data.table as well. 
Is this a bug or a feature of the package? or am I doing something horribly wrong?

```
a<-data.table(x=1:100,y=1:100)

b<-a

b[,x:=2]

head(a)

head(b)
```

Comment: You may need `b <- copy(a)` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys. copy(a) does work :)